# Version strings for Windows drivers

Tags: windows, msbuild, drivers

We currently use this value in our resource file:

```
#define VER_FILEVERSION             4,0,0,5
#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "4.0.0.5"
```

In the INF file for the driver (after the build), the version shows up as:

```
DriverVer = 10/25/2017,"4.0.0.5"
```

Is it possible that we can increase the number of version digits to 6? I would like my version to look like: `4.0.0.5.0.1`

I have already seen: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/inf-driver-version-entry

They do not have any information that talks about more than 4 digits, all they mention is that the version number is optional.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: I can't find anything in that link to support your claim

Comment: Wrong link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-driverver-directive

Comment: I still can't find a reference to a 6 part version number. You should quote the article in addition to the link. It shows a set of four 16-bit integer, example `1.0.65535.65535`

Comment: That is my question, is it possible to have a 6 part version? The above mentioned links talk about a 4 part version

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. No, there is no 6 part versions.